# Group method of insert nil - yet I know it isn't

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I am using Corona SDK to write an iOS app.  The app is completed, but I have found a bug with storyboard.  After opening several different storyboard scenes and returning back to this one scene I get an error (see below).  It is seemingly random, in the way that I can return to the scene 4 or 5 times with no issue, but other times it might appear the first time I return.  I can only assume this is down to Corona's internal handling of scenes where it purges scenes when memory usage hits a certain level.

The error I am receiving is:

```
Runtime error
    /Users/**/contact.lua:124: attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'insert'
    /Users/**/contact.lua:124: in function 'renderPage'
    /Users/**/contact.lua:179: in function </Users/**/contact.lua:166>
```

The code producing this error is below.  Please note that this code works perfectly the first time it is opened, and it takes a random number of scene changes before the error appears.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- contact.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local widget = require( "widget" )
local tableView = require( "tableViewXL" )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
-- 
-- NOTE: Code outside of listener functions (below) will only be executed once,
--       unless storyboard.removeScene() is called.
-- 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    local function openMenu()
        transition.to( menu, { x = 0, time=600, transition=easing.outQuad } )
        this_window = 'contact'
        native.cancelWebPopup()
    end

    local openBtn = ui.newButton{
        defaultSrc = 'images/menu.png',
        defaultX = 29,
        defaultY = 29,
        overSrc = 'images/menu.png',
        overX = 29,
        overY = 29,
        overAlpha = .5,
        onEvent = openMenu,
        text = "",
        size = 14,
        textColor = { 138, 173, 189, 255 },
        font = system.nativeFont,
        emboss = false,
        id = "Button",
    }
    openBtn.x = 28; openBtn.y = 28



    -- add background and logout button
    local bg = display.newImageRect( "images/background.png", 320, 480 )
    bg:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
    bg.x = 0; bg.y = 0;

    -- Date
    local date = txt.newEmbossed(os.date("%d/%m/%y"), 10, 60, native.systemFontBold, 12)
    date:setTextColor( 55, 96, 127 )    -- blue
    date:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    date.x = 280
    date.y = 84

    -- Title
    local title = txt.new( "Contact", 17, 72, 'Georgia', 20 )
    title:setTextColor( 71, 24, 76 )

    -- Called when the API is able to return user info (fb page, twitter, etc)
    function renderPage( data )

        local textAddress = txt.new( data.address, 17, 120, native.systemFont, 14, display.TopLeftReferencePoint, 300, 200 )
        textAddress:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )     

        local phoneBar = display.newImageRect( "images/contact/phoneBar.png", 296, 24 )
        phoneBar.x = (display.contentWidth * 0.5); phoneBar.y = 230
        local phoneText = txt.new( data.phone, 20, 222, native.systemFont, 12, display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
        phoneText:setTextColor( 70, 24, 72 )

        local emailBar = display.newImageRect( "images/contact/emailBar.png", 296, 24 )
        emailBar.x = (display.contentWidth * 0.5); emailBar.y = 260
        local emailText = txt.new( data.email, 20, 252, native.systemFont, 12, display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
        emailText:setTextColor( 70, 24, 72 )

        local twitterBar = display.newImageRect( "images/contact/twitterBar.png", 296, 24 )
        twitterBar.x = (display.contentWidth * 0.5); twitterBar.y = 290
        local twitterText = txt.new( 'Twitter - @'.. data.twitter, 20, 282, native.systemFont, 12, display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
        twitterText:setTextColor( 70, 24, 72 )

        local facebookBar = display.newImageRect( "images/contact/facebookBar.png", 296, 24 )
        facebookBar.x = (display.contentWidth * 0.5); facebookBar.y = 320
        local facebookText = txt.new( 'Facebook', 20, 312, native.systemFont, 12, display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
        facebookText:setTextColor( 70, 24, 72 )

        local function phoneTouch( event )
            if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
                system.openURL( "tel:".. data.phone )
            end
        end
        local function emailTouch( event )
            if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
                system.openURL( "mailto:".. data.email )
            end
        end
        local function twitterTouch( event )
            if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
                system.openURL( "https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=".. data.twitter )
            end
        end
        local function facebookTouch( event )
            if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
                system.openURL( "fb://profile/".. data.facebook )
            end
        end

        phoneBar:addEventListener( 'touch', phoneTouch )
        phoneText:addEventListener( 'touch', phoneTouch )
        emailBar:addEventListener( 'touch', emailTouch )
        emailText:addEventListener( 'touch', emailTouch )
        twitterBar:addEventListener( 'touch', twitterTouch )
        twitterText:addEventListener( 'touch', twitterTouch )
        facebookBar:addEventListener( 'touch', facebookTouch )
        facebookText:addEventListener( 'touch', facebookTouch )

        print ( textAddress )

        group:insert( textAddress )     
        group:insert( phoneBar )        
        group:insert( phoneText )       
        group:insert( emailBar )        
        group:insert( emailText )       
        group:insert( twitterBar )      
        group:insert( twitterText )     
        group:insert( facebookBar )
        group:insert( facebookText )

        phoneText:toFront()
        emailText:toFront()
        twitterText:toFront()
        facebookText:toFront()

        -- Add the map
        -- Load map template from a file
        local path = system.pathForFile( "map_template.html", system.ResourceDirectory )

        local file = io.open( path, "r" )

        local mapTemplate = file:read( "*a" )
        io.close( file )
        -- Add in our address and write to another file
        address = data.address1
        if(data.address2 == '' and data.address2 ~= '') then address = address .. ', ' .. data.address2 end
        if(data.citytown == '' and data.citytown ~= '') then address = address .. ', ' .. data.citytown end
        if(data.county == '' and data.county ~= '') then address = address .. ', ' .. data.county end
        if(data.postcode == '' and data.postcode ~= '') then address = address .. ', ' .. data.postcode end

        mapTemplate = string.gsub( mapTemplate, "||ADDRESS||", address )
        -- Now save it to a local file
        local path = system.pathForFile( "map.html", system.DocumentsDirectory )
        local file = io.open( path, "w" )
        file:write( mapTemplate )
        io.close( file )

        local options = { hasBackground=false, baseUrl=system.DocumentsDirectory, urlRequest=listener }
        native.showWebPopup( 0, 345, display.contentWidth, 130, "map.html", options )
    end


    function api.networkListener( event )
        native.setActivityIndicator( false )
        if ( event.isError ) then
            native.showAlert( "Error", "Sorry, there was a problem communicating with the server.", {"Ok"} )
        else
            json = require "json"
            local response = json.decode( event.response )
            if(response.error) then
                native.showAlert( "Error", response.error, {"Ok"} )

            else                

                data = response
                renderPage( data )
            end
        end
        return event.response
    end

    native.setActivityIndicator( true )
    api.request( 'users/me', "GET" )


    -- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
    group:insert( bg )
    group:insert( date )
    group:insert( title )
    group:insert( openBtn )

end

-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listenets, unload sounds, etc.)
    native.cancelWebPopup()
end

-- If scene's view is removed, scene:destroyScene() will be called just prior to:
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. remove listeners, remove widgets, save state variables, etc.)
    native.cancelWebPopup()

end

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched whenever before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

I have tried purging this scene when another is opened.  When printing `group` or `textAddress` both are tables, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that between `renderPage` calls the value of `group` variable (which points to the save object as `self.view` when first called) changes. You mentioned that you are printing `group` and `textAddress`. Can you also print `group.insert` value?

```
    print ( textAddress, group, group.insert )

    group:insert( textAddress ) <-- line 124
```

The following fragment would trigger the same error:

```
local scene = { view = { insert = function(...) print(...) end }}

function scene:createScene( event )
  local group = self.view

  function renderPage( data )
    group:insert( 'foo ' .. data )     
  end
end

scene:createScene()
renderPage(11)
renderPage(12)

scene.view.insert = nil
renderPage(13)
```

Note that you recreate `renderPage` every time you create a new scene and the new `renderPage` refers to the `group` variable from the newly created scene (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: to elaborate on the above, when your code calls api.networkListener the listener it calls might be one that was created on a previous instance of the page (which has subsequently been removed).  This might happen in the case of a very slow network call or one where you rapidly leave the scene.  It's not obvious in the provided code but are you cancelling your network requests elsewhere in the app?

Comment: `print ( textAddress, group, group.insert )` shows: `table: 0x10b778750 table: 0x10b7b8a90 function: 0x102a5bbd0`.  That leads me to believe that it should be working just fine - but it still isn't.  I have also placed all of the code int he network listener, effectively removing the renderPage() method, but still get the same error

Comment: @mikemike, this particular error seems to be popular on Corona forums: [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=attempt+to+call+method+%27insert%27+%28a+nil+value%29+%22in+function+insert%22); there are some suggestions you may want to try [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/11/07/weird-error-enterframe-event).